# Singularity at infinity of a function entire

Tags: complex-analysis

How to prove that every non-constant entire function $\,\,f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\,\,$ has a singularity at infinity?

What type of singularity must this be?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Given a function $f(z)$, we say that $f$ has a singularity (of a given type) at infinity if and only if $f(\frac1z)$ has a singularity (of said type) at $0$.

By Liouville's Theorem, we know that every *bounded* entire function is constant. Conversely, it's clear that every constant function (with a non-infinite constant) is bounded and entire.

Suppose $f$ is a non-constant entire function, so that $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n,$$ where the radius of convergence of this power series is infinite, and there is at least one $n\geq 1$ such that $a_n\neq0$.

Since $$f\left(\frac1z\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{z^n}=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{z^n},$$ and since $a_n\neq 0$ for some $n>0$, then $f$ has a singularity at infinity--that is, the Laurent expansion of $f(\frac1z)$ about $z=0$ has a non-zero singular part. If there are only finitely-many non-zero $a_n$'s, then $f$ has a pole at infinity. Otherwise, $f$ has an essential singularity at infinity.

Comment: The "and since $a_n \ne 0$ for some $n > 0$, then $f$ has a singularity at infinity" needs some elucidation.

Comment: Is that more straightforward, Robert?

Comment: As a student (and for future students who may end up here), an important takeaway from this statement is that if $f(\frac{1}{z})$ has a pole at $z = 0$, then the finitely many $a_n$ indicates that $f(z)$ is a polynomial. It's obvious from what you've said, but nonetheless, that realization is incredibly helpful

Answer (score 31):

Technically, $f$ has a singularity at $\infty$ by virtue of not being defined there.  What is really meant is that a non-constant entire function $f$ has a *non-removable* singularity at $\infty$, and this follows directly from Liouville's theorem: if the singularity at $\infty$ was removable, $f$ would be bounded in a neighbourhood of $\infty$, say $\{z: |z| \ge r\}$, and since $f$ is also bounded on $\{z: |z| \le r\}$ (because a continuous function is bounded on a compact set) $f$ would be bounded on $\mathbb C$, therefore constant by Liouville's theorem.

Comment: This one is short and sweet. I like this one better. Just wondering if it make any difference while you take the neighborhood of infinity open set not the closed like you did in the proof you gave?

Comment: Loved this answer.

Answer (score 7):

Just to give an example.

Clearly $f$ is unbounded near $\infty$ so the singularity cannot be removable.

If $f(z)=az+b$ where $a\neq 0$ , then $f$ has a pole at $\infty$.

If $f(z)=e^z$, then $f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$.